# Counting a specific number of weekdays within a specific year error

Tags: python, calendar, iteration

I am trying to utilize python's `calendar` module to count the number of specific weekdays throughout a specific year.

For example, number of Mondays in 2020.

The issue that I'm having is that the result is about ~10 more than what it should be for any type of input. Here is my code:

```
import calendar


class MyCalendar(calendar.Calendar):

    def __init__(self):
        self.setfirstweekday(calendar.SUNDAY)

    def count_weekday_in_year(self, year, weekday):
        counter = 0
        yearDays = []
        for x in range(1,13):
            yearDays.append(list(self.monthdays2calendar(year, x)))

        print("Working on the following list: \n", yearDays)

        for x in yearDays:
            for y in x:
                for z in y:
                    if z[1] == weekday:
                        counter+=1
        return counter


mc = MyCalendar()
print(mc.count_weekday_in_year(2000, 6))
```

For example, `year=2000, weekday=6` is supposed to return 53, but I get 64.

I know that I have a counting error. I just don't know where. I also know that my way of navigating the multiple layers of the list is not the most ideal.

Comment: Put the counter logic in the first loop. There is no reason to have two loops: it just makes things harder to debug. When you debug, print out all relevant info and find out when you increment on a day you aren't supposed to. I suspect it's because calendar generally aligns on week boundaries, so it duplicates the days at the start and end of each month.

Comment: I think this must be possible without loops. Weekdays are after all 7 days apart, so you just need to now when the first weekday appears, and if there are 51 or 52 of the weekdays after this.

Comment: Why is your code so complicated? There don't need to be any loops in this at all. All you need is the day-of-year of the first Monday and the day-of-year of the last Monday. Then it's an arithmetic calculation

Comment: @PranavHosangadi. Debugging the code is a completely different problem from solving the problem efficiently. I've posted an answer with the efficient solution instead of actually answering the question :)

Comment: @MadPhysicist I know! and it showed up right as I was about to submit mine which was essentially the same thing. :)

Comment: @PranavHosangadi. I'm going to update tho. To answer your actual question, OP is a beginner just learning the tools. Unfortunately, date and time computations, and the Calendar class in particular, are not good places to start with coding.

Comment: @MadPhysicist The question was rhetorical, haha.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi. Unfortunately I'm very literal :)

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm for how to count occurrences of a weekday in a given year does not really require iteration. It's just a problem of finding how many weeks fit in the part of the year starting with the first occurrence of the weekday.

The information you need:

- Length of year (varies by year)
- First weekday of year (varies by year)
- Length of week (probably 7)
- Selected day (user input)

You can compute the first (zero based) occurrence of your selected day with

```
offset = (selected_day - first_weekday_of_year) % length_of_week
```

This works out of the box in python because the result of modulo (`%`) always takes the sign of the second operand in python.

The number of times the selected day occurs is going to be the number of weeks you can fit into `length_of_year - offset`, with the understanding that you only need to offset by one because you're starting at the selected day:

```
occurrences = 1 + (length_of_year - offset - 1) // length_of_week
```

Answer (score 2):

Mad Physicist's hunch is absolutely correct. monthdays2calendar() gives full weeks, including days that belong to the next month, but fall within a week that contains days from this month.
It helps to keep track of things if you name variables appropriately, so I reworded the loop a little bit. Besides that, the other important thing is that, in the Calendar library, days that lie outside of the given month are given "0" as their "Day of the month" index - so in order to properly account for this, we need to exclude any days that have this "day of the month" equal to zero, like so:

```
    for month in yearDays:
        for week in month:
            for day_of_month, day_of_week in week:
                if day_of_month == 0:
                    continue
                if day_of_week == weekday:
                    counter+=1
```

With this change in place, we see 53 as the final output of the program

Comment: To be fair, it's more than a hunch. I've seen what calendar does :)

Answer (score 1):

General solution applied to Mondays in 2020:

```py
import datetime


def count_weekdays(year: int, target_weekday: int):
    d = datetime.date(year, 1, 1)
    d += datetime.timedelta(days=(target_weekday - d.weekday()) % 7)
    
    time_span = datetime.date(year, 12, 31) - d
    return (time_span // 7).days + 1

# monday == 0 (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.weekday)
mondays_in_2020 = count_weekdays(2020, 0) # 52
```

Comment: I can't test it right now, so I hope you did :)

Comment: Don't have the audacity to post untested code :P

Comment: 90% of my posts are from mobile (including my answer here :).

Answer (score 0):

To find the number of Mondays or Sundays in a year, I used this, where data is a list generated  from `monthdays2calendar(year, month)` (List with 7 tuples `[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (1, 5), (2, 6)]`). If the first element of any tuple is 0, it means that the day is from the previous month or from the next month, generated to complete the week, so this `element[0] = 0` should not be count.

```
import calendar

class MyCalendar(calendar.Calendar):
    def __init__(self):
       self.setfirstweekday(calendar.MONDAY)

    def count_weekday_in_year(self, year, weekday):
        counter = 0
        for month in range(1,13):
            for data in self.monthdays2calendar(year,month):
                for element in data:
                    if element[0] != 0 and element[1] == weekday:
                        counter +=1
                
        return counter
        
mc = MyCalendar()
print(mc.count_weekday_in_year(2019,0)) #52
print(mc.count_weekday_in_year(2000,6)) #53
```